# indexOf() and Boyer Moore methods

Tags: java, strings, search

I have a method I created which is a custom `indexOf()`. This code seems ugly to me so I was wondering if anyone could recommend a cleaner and perhaps faster implementation of my method.

```
public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, char[] substr, int index) {
    if (str == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if (substr.length > str.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (substr.length == 0 && index >= str.length) {
        return str.length;
    }
    if (substr.length == 0 && index >= 0) {
        return index;
    }
    if (substr.length == 0 && index < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (substr.length == 0 && str.length == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    int[] found = boyerMoore(str, substr);
    for (int i : found) {
        if (i >= index) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // can not found substring after index
    return -1;
}

// Don't necessarily need any modification for this method. But for those who are interested
Boyer Moore:

public static int[] boyerMoore(char[] str, char[] substr) { 
    // index array of indexes of found substrings
    // initialize
    int indexCounter = 0;
    int[] subStringIndex = new int[str.length];
    for (int c = 0; c < str.length; c++) {
        subStringIndex[c] = -1;
    }
    // character set ASCII
    int characterSet = 256;
    // initialize
    int[] charSet = new int[characterSet];
    for (int a = 0; a < characterSet; a++) {
        charSet[a] = -1;
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < substr.length; b++) {
        charSet[substr[b]] = b;
    }

    int skip;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (str.length - substr.length); i += skip) {
        //System.out.print(i);
        skip = 0;
        for (int j = substr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (substr[j] != str[i + j]) {
                skip = Math.max(1, j - charSet[str[i + j]]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (skip == 0) {
            // increment next value in String
            skip++;
            // add found substring (beginning index)
            subStringIndex[indexCounter] = i;
            indexCounter++;
            // this last bit is used if Boyer Moore stops searching after first instance is found
            // return i;

        }
    }

    return  subStringIndex;
    // This bit is used when Boyer Moore is stops after the first instance in found
    // cannot be found
    // return str.length;
}
```

Comment: It seems the Boyer Moore part is missing?

Comment: @konijn to boyer Moore part is on the bottom. I modded it to return an `in[]` if more than one instance of the substring is found

Comment: I am a stupid user, I did not see the scroll bar, sorry

Comment: @konijn dont be so hard on yourself =D

Answer (score 5):

**Naming**

- Choose an existing idiom such as "find a needle in a haystack" and consider putting the parameters in that order.
- The name `index` implies some generic location within `haystack`. However, `start` makes it clear why that index is significant.

The rest of my answer assumes these changes.

**Validating Input**

- You don't need to manually throw `NullPointerException` for `null` values when accessing the length of each string will do it automatically. If not, make sure to check *both* strings for consistency.
- Consider how to handle negative values for `start`, typically by taking it from the end of the haystack. You'll need to decide whether to use modulo arithmetic or constrain overly-negative values to zero.

  ```
  if start < 0
      start = Math.max(0, haystack.length + start)
  ```

**Logic Yoga**

- Combine identical prefix expressions in an `if` chain.

  ```
  if (A && R) { X }
  if (A && S) { Y }
  if (A && T) { Z }
  ```

  This can be [simplified and optimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to

  ```
  if (A) {
      if (R) { X }
      if (S) { Y }
      if (T) { Z }
  }
  ```

  It works for `||` as well, though I can't think of a recent sighting in the wild.

  ```
  if (A || R) { X }
  if (A || S) { Y }
  if (A || T) { Z }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  if (A)
      X Y Z
  else
      // same as "if (A)" above
  ```
- Clarify intent by using `else if` after blocks that should exit. Adding `else` lets the compiler *enforce* that intent when they're modified.

  ```
  myIndexOf(needle, haystack, start)
      if needle is larger than haystack
          return ...
      else if needle is empty
          return ...
      else
          return ...
  ```

**Extract Methods**

- Move generic helper methods such as constraining an index to a library. Apache Commons probably has one. This way someone doesn't have to read the code three times to infer its intended purpose (versus what it actually does). Here `index` makes more sense without a context.

  ```
  constrain(index, size)
      return Math.max(0, Math.min(index, size))
  ```
- Separate parameter checking from the raw search algorithm when either is long enough.

  ```
  findBoyerMore(needle, haystack, start)
      for index in boyerMoore(needle, haystack)
          if index >= start
              return index
      return -1
  ```
- Extract a method to test if `needle` can fit inside `haystack` at `start`.

  Also, you can [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) in the case of `myIndexOf("foo", "foobar", 5)` without calling `boyerMoore` even though `foo` is shorter than `foobar`. Take `start` into consideration when comparing the length of the two strings.

  ```
  canFitAt(needle, haystack, start)
      return start + needle.length <= haystack.length
  ```

**Dead Code**

- Since `index >= 0` and `index < 0` cannot both fail, `if (substr.length == 0 && str.length == 0)` cannot succeed and can be removed.

**End Result**

Combining all of the above gives us a much-simplified method.

```
myIndexOf(needle, haystack, start)
    if canFitAt(needle, haystack, start)
        return findBoyerMoore(needle, haystack, start)
    else
        return constrain(start, haystack.length)
```

Comment: I would say your `||` expansion is not an improvement as it is severely not DRY.

Comment: @NetMage Sometimes violating guidelines like DRY can improve readability. The key is recognizing when to break them. ;)

Comment: In this case I would suggest it is asking for a future maintenance error, however, when Y is changed in one place.

Comment: @NetMage And what about when `A` is changed in only one place? This is a seriously contrived example no one will encounter in the wild. There's no 100% correct answer to the trade-off of "DRY vs. readablity". That's what makes it a trade-off, and programming is full of them.